# Mailgun fails sending emails to addresses owned by domain registar

Tags: wordpress, mailgun

I'm trying to use MailGun for a WordPress site using the official MailGun plugin, we've sent a bunch of test emails now and they all get delivered, except to addresses owned by my domain registar (tested with gmail, yahoo, office365).

When we asked their support they simply said "We don't accept emails from made up addresses", which makes sense but we have followed the mailgun guide, the domain is set as verified in mailgun and sends just fine to the other mail addresses we checked.

The domain is also used for a gmail addresse (paid gmail)

here is a screenshot from my CNAME and TXT records 
[image: image from domain cname/txt]

Mailgun has verified the domain 
[image: domain and dns verification]

I thought that I did not need to pay for email at my domain provider as well as gmail, is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing MX records for the subdomain (mx..no>), after adding the mx records from mailgun everything is working as expected. Still weird that gmail and office365 tok emails and not my domain provider.

Edit: if you read and follow this PLEASE remember to set the MX value in your settings as lower than the MX value for gmail.